# Media query element does not disappear

Tags: css, media-queries, prestashop-1.6

I have, on a Prestashop store, a copyright paragraph that I want to dispaly on a single row for large displays and with a linebreak for smaller ones (ie. mobile).
I have created two distinct ids for two versions of the copyright text like this:

```css
    @media (max-width: 719px) {#poweredby {display: none;}}
      @media (min-width: 720px) {#poweredby {text-align: center;margin: -10px 0 -13px 0;display: block;}}
      @media (max-width: 719px) {#poweredby-mob {display: block;}}
      @media (min-width: 720px) {#poweredby-mob {display: none!important;}}
```

```html
 <div id="poweredby" class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
    COPY 1 - Single line
    </div>
    <div id="poweredby-mob" class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
    COPY 2 - Two lines
    </div>
```

The result though is strange:
on mobile displays only the "poweredby-mob" div is visible, like it should, but on larger ones they BOTH appear, "poweredby-mob" not getting the display:none attribute even if I added !important to it.

Any ideas why this simple media query isn't working?

Comment: Could you put some example (fiddle, codepen, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Media queries can be picky about how you structure them. Try this.

```
@media (max-width: 719px) {
    #poweredby {display: none;}
    #poweredby-mob {display: block;}
}
@media (min-width: 720px) {
    #poweredby {text-align: center;margin: -10px 0 -13px 0;display: block;}
    #poweredby-mob {display: none!important;}
}
```

Another thing that can help is to choose a "default", whether that be mobile or non-mobile and set those style outside of any media queries. Then use media queries only to override when needed. That reduces the potential for human error.

Comment: Simplified structure works and actually makes sense.
Many thanks. I will remember this piece of advice.